# $S_n$={$x∈Z^+$|n divides x} I don't get the meaning

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For each $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is defined by : $S_n =\{x\in \mathbb{Z}^+|n \mbox{ divides } x\}$;
express in simplest terms the membership of  $S_6 \backslash S_3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n$ divides $x$ then $x$ is a multiple of $n$. So $S_n$ is the set of all multiples of $n$.

And $\setminus$ is the set-minus symbol. So you're asked to describe the set of all positive integers which are in $S_6$ but *not* in $S_3$.

Comment: Therefore, in this case, it has no solution, doesn't it?

Comment: And set language has a useful way to write down a collection of no things.